# JSON array undefined & empty in promise Bluebird

Tags: json, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am using Promise bluebird to process a json array objects from file. The problem arises if I want to store data in a json array (called list) and return this in the final process.
The list is empty/undefined after the return of list or even in the final process. Running the code, I always have 1 value that is not false which trigger the adding/push of the json in the list.

Can you help me with this issue? Below you will find my code.

Thanks in advance !!!

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var join = Promise.join;
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

fs.readdirAsync(dir).map(function (filename) {
    return fs.readFileAsync(dir + "/" + filename, "utf8");
}).then(function(result){
    var list=[];

    result.map(function(row, index){
      Promise.coroutine(function*() {
        update(row, index).then(function(value){
          if (value!=false){
            var trade_update = new updated_Item(row.ID, row.Quantity, row.Price, row.Remark);
            list.push(trade_update);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(list));          <-- This works. It gives me data
          }
          return list;
        })
      })();
    });
    console.log('list: ' + JSON.stringify(list));        <-- output:    list:[]
    return list;
}).finally(function(result){
  console.log('Final outcome: '+ ' ' + JSON.stringify(result));      <-- output: Final outcome: undefined
})
```

With the help of Samuel my code is now:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var join = Promise.join;
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));


function updateOrder(done){
  fs.readdirAsync(dir).map(function (filename) {
      return fs.readFileAsync(dir + "/" + filename, "utf8");
  }).then(function(result){
    var list=[];

    result.map(function(row, index){
      Promise.coroutine(function*() {
        update(row, index).then(function(value){
          if (value!=false){
            var trade_update = new updated_Item(row.ID, row.Quantity, row.Price, row.Remark);
            list.push(trade_update);
            done(list);      
          }
        })
      })();
    });

    //done(list);   <--if I put the done callback here, it will give me an empty list. I though once the result.map finished processing all the values give me the end result.
  }
}

updateOrder(function(resultList){
  console.log('List' + JSON.stringify(resultList));
})
```

This code give me whole resultList everytime the list has been updated (pushed) now.

I would to receive the resultList at the end once the function updateOrder is finished.

Comment: `Promise.coroutine` is asynchronous, so `list` will not get any values until later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comment. `Promise.coroutine` is asynchronous so this means that a result is not going to get return straight after your code reaches it. And this pretty much explains the phenomenon you are seeing where the latter print statements you got in the code is suggesting that `list` is undefined.

What you could do is wrap the entire code you got there in a function, then add a `callback` function as a parameter for the `async` functions to invoke when it has finished its duty, together returning the populated list back for later processing.

I have written a pseudo code for your case, unfortunately I couldn't test it on my IDE but the concept is there and it should work.

Consider my pseudo code:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var join = Promise.join;
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));

// Wrap everything you got into a function with a `done` parameter (callback fn)
function doStuff(done) {
  fs.readdirAsync(dir).map(function (filename) {
    return fs.readFileAsync(dir + "/" + filename, "utf8");
  }).then(function(result){
    var list=[];

    result.map(function(row, index){
      Promise.coroutine(function*() {
        update(row, index).then(function(value){
          if (value!=false){
            var trade_update = new updated_Item(row.ID, row.Quantity, row.Price, row.Remark);
            list.push(trade_update);
          }
          done(list);
        })
      })();
    });
  }).finally(function(result){
    console.log('File read finish, but this doesnt mean I have finished doing everything!');
  })
}

// call your function and provide a callback function for the async method to call 
doStuff(function(resultList) {
  console.log('list: ' + JSON.stringify(resultList));
  // Continue processing the list data.
});
```

Comment: @BigSkinny let me know if this solution makes sense to you, happy to discuss further

Comment: Hi Samuel Toh, it works. I now get the list. I have put the done(list); inside the if function and removed the finally function since it has no added value. Great, thank you for your help!!!

Comment: Now the done parameter will be called at every run of the result.map. I try to change it, just to call the done parameter once everything is finished by moving the done(list) to another place down in the code, but the resultList is empty if I move it. Any idea why this is?

Comment: I mean, only receive the resultList once everything is completed in the doStuff function

Comment: @BigSkinny For me to diagnose your issue much easier, do  you want to raise another question with your updated source code? It can be quite difficult for me to figure out your current state without looking at any code. If you do raise another question just give me a ping. Thanks

Comment: I have put my code here above what I am trying to figure out

Comment: @BigSkinny yes that is correct code behavior the reason why the `callback` isn't returning anything was because `Promise.coroutine` is asynchronous. The code will process `result.map`, basically looping through all elements and then without waiting for the function `Promise.coroutine` to response, the next line of code it would execute will be your *commented* callback `done()` function. Of course, since nothing has been returned yet, `list` would be undefined. Hence it is returning an undefined value for the callback. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also note that, the inner function that you defined for `Promise.coroutine` (The part where you got `list.push`), this bit doesn't get called until later sometime. As for when? It gets called when the task is done. Definitely not immediate. Remember, Javascript is single threaded, it will continously keeps running a single piece of code until it is done. Then when the current code is done running it then looks at what is next to process, the next code to run could be the nested function u defined for `Promise.coroutine`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will check how to execute the done callback at the end. For me it is difficult as a beginner in the world of (a)synchronous.

Comment: Is it possible to do a callback at the end of the result.map process so just once the callback instead of every iteration?

Comment: Yes it is possible so instead of doing a `map` call which would fire off all the async call at once. You might want to consider using recursive function, that is you only fire off the next async call when the previous one is finished, Then when no more call is needed, invoke the `done` callback function.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I use the promise.all in the result.map to solve it.